# Как правильно голосовать за спам в очереди проверок?

Tags: поддержка, спам

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/171007

В вопрос я сходил, тревогу спама поставил, а что в очереди-то выбирать?
<kbd>Пропустить</kbd> - верно?

[image: скриншот вариантов]

И вообще, не хватает тревог в очереди.

Comment: Открыть вопрос в соседнем табе, поставить тревогу, закрыть таб.

Comment: @VladD, так я так и сделал. А в очереди-то что жать?

Comment: Разве "Закрыть" не единственно разумный вариант из представленных тут? Ну можно еще "пропустить", если не уверен :)

Comment: @alexolut, вроде как он не подходит, а то получится [очередное](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) ... [Спам не требует-правки](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/972/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy если спам уже флагнут, то для экономии голосов на закрытие в очереди можно действительно выбрать "пропустить".

Comment: @alexolut, это не та очередь - это ж low quality, а не close.

Comment: Не важно. Любая очередь лимитирована посуточно.

Comment: Это по идее значит, что на кнопку «закрыть» следует добавить причину «спам», которая ведёт не на «требует правки», а именно на «закрыть». Ну да, кастомная логика, где-то в движке нужен целый if.